# Window Onfocus Process in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular v5 and wanted to know what the equivalent is for the following, specifically the `$window.onfocus` as this doesn't work in Angular

```
$window.onfocus = function() {     
   console.log("****user attempted leaving but changed its mind, do actions here");
}
```

I need to determine window focus within my TypeScript code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@HostListener` decorator to register `window.focus` event in your component

and then

```
@HostListener('window:focus', ['$event'])
onFocus(event) {
    console.log("****user attempted leaving but changed its mind, do actions here");
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mfbl8)

You can try running the demo [url](https://angular-2mfbl8.stackblitz.io)  in your browser tab.

Comment: Hi Amit - sorry but I don't understand your demo and how it relates back to your answer. Can you pls explain.

Comment: The demo link has the code shown in my answer, which also opens the deafult run window. If you want to see the console log, you have to run that in the main browser and switch between the window tabs.. so that you can see the log.. The URL in answer is the direct link to run window.