# Angular 2 Event listener on document inside a component

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i set up an event listener (`mouseup`) in angular 2  inside a component that can be triggered by all the document ? the callback function would call a function inside the component

Something like this (In Javascript):

```
document.addEventListerner('mouseup', function(){
    if( condition ){
       // code ..
    }
});
```

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860593/window-onfocus-process-in-angular/50860957#50860957 Instead use `mouseup` event

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2iktzs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-host-listener-mouseup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `HostListener` to register an event on the document object

```
import {HostListener, KeyboardEvent} from '@angular/core';
```

inside the component

```
  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  mouseUp(ev:KeyboardEvent) { 
    console.log(ev);
  }
```

Comment: this work, but only in the component zone, to make it work i did: @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])

Comment: yes. either you have to create a common component and reuse it or create a service and call it form the component

Answer (score 0):

Use `@HostListener` decorator to register `mouseup` event in your component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2iktzs

```
@HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseUp(event) {
  console.log("mouse clicked and released");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For using mouse up event in angular, make a directive and using host listener you can fire event. 
After declaring directive in app.module, use the selector name with html attributes/tags.

```
import { Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
    // Directive to for mouse up event
    @Directive({
        selector: '[mouseup]'
    })

    export class MouseUpDirective {

        private el: any;

        constructor( el: ElementRef ) {
            this.el = el.nativeElement;
        }

        @HostListener('mouseup')
        onMouseUp() {
            this.highlight('yellow');
        }

        private highlight(color: string) {
            this.el.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.